# switch login screen to home firebase and google

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, authentication, expo

I have no idea how I can get through the google login from the login to home screen

I want to perform an action that when the user clicks login with google it checks if it's right and goes straight to home

```
<!-- language: Js -->
screen config Firebase


    import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
    import { getAuth, GoogleAuthProvider, signInWithPopup } from "firebase/auth";
  
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "AIzaSyADaTNLtR-zJyY2JGbiIjxEqyIRSEvOB0g",
      authDomain: "projetotcc-d6d47.firebaseapp.com",
      databaseURL: "https://projetotcc-d6d47-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com",
      projectId: "projetotcc-d6d47",
      storageBucket: "projetotcc-d6d47.appspot.com",
      messagingSenderId: "1041839304552",
      appId: "1:1041839304552:web:e862a59abc6c747d6730dd",
      measurementId: "G-D8CEEJPRVS"
    };


    const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
    export const auth = getAuth(app);

    const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

    export const signInWithGoogle = () => {

      signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
        .then((result) => {
          const name = result.user.displayName;
          const userid = result.user.uid;
          const email = result.user.email;
          const profilePic = result.user.photoURL;


          localStorage.setItem("name", name);
          localStorage.setItem("email", email);
          localStorage.setItem("userid", userid);
          localStorage.setItem("profilePic", profilePic);
         
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });

        
    };
```

Comment: i'm using react native

Answer (score 0):

You need to set-up a listener that will check whether a user is logged in or not, and depending on this display either the authentication screen or the home screen.

[Check this doc](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage) to know how to do this and an example. Also, [this doc](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/social-auth#google) for sing-in with Google.